# adding and subtracting cells in excel

Tags: macos, excel, osx-mountain-lion

say I have 7 groups of columns of 2 columns and each group of column represent one day " Monday Tuesdays ect... & in one group of columns there's either "win" or "lost" so I want to add all those columns so that win add up and lost subtract automatically. I have it set up so that it can only be one "win" or  one "lost" in each group of 2 columns.  for exp: {a(win) b(lost)} {c(win) d(lost)}

so I want if a is "a" win and " c" is win and "f" is a lost  and "h" is a lost  and "I" is a win  ect... to all come up to a total

exp: a[1234] +c[1234] - f[1234] -h[1234] = [total]

i want my lose to be shown in negative ...

HOW CAN I MAKE A WHOLE COLUMN SHOW UP HAS NEGATIVE VALUE EVERYTIME I ENTER A NUMBER LIKE : -1234 IF I ENTER 1234 IN THE "LOSE" COLUMN

Comment: I would suggest making an ASCII-art example of your columns, wins and losses, rather than the description you have going here. That way we can hopefully follow you better...

Comment: Better if you can attach screenshot. So that we can better a good understand

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sum the number of wins and loses you can use `COUNTIF` on the ranges you care about, e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(B4:B13,"Win") -COUNTIF(B4:B13,"Loss")
```

You'll need to change the `B4:B13` ranges to match wherever you are tracking wins/loses and change the "Win" and "Loss" strings to match whatever indicates whether a given day was a win or a loss.  If you want to apply different scoring to wins vs. losses just multiply the `COUNTIF` statements by your scoring values.

Comment: no i want my lose number to be shown in - ( negative ) so if there is more lose than win it will show has negative not positive

Comment: That's what this does.  Suppose you have 2 wins and 5 loses, this will  calculate (2-5) and display a value of -3.  What are you seeing it do?

Comment: I won't work for me like that because my total are by rows not by columns and each columns represent 1 win & 1 lose

Comment: I won't work for me like that because my total are by rows not by columns each day have 2 columns [win]~[loss] for exp: Monday have 2 columns & each columns has 157 rows each row represent one person & depending on what come in its either win or loss so on Monday is could be win on tues it could be also win on Wednesday it could be lost on Thursday it could be also loss and Friday win on Saturday also win & on Sunday it's loss I want it  to add & to subtract automatic & if the negative over power the positive number be be shown in the total has negative i hope I cleared it out for you. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm really not clear on what you need.  Like others suggested, posting a screenshot or an ASCII table would help a lot.  I'm unclear whether you are trying to generate the total Win/Loss value for each individual, or the net wins/losses for all individuals on a given day.

Comment: so since i cannot post picture i have upload it to icloud !   https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#A15oqs3qGUArZi   ignore the words in french lundi is monday and dimanche is sunday  green is win and red is perte. there can only one win or one perte for each day and i want it to add if its green or subtract if its red and the total to be done if there is more red than green the the total should be exp: -1234

Comment: What value are you going to type in a cell if a player has a win or a loss?  Is it going to be a number (0 vs. 1)?  Is it going to be text?  If it's a number, I think what pnuts described above is what you'd want.

Comment: it will be numbers "$" so player can win (0) to infinity and a player can lose (0) to (-infinity) <---- that will be negative number

Comment: i posted another picture https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#A15oqs3qGUArZi to show how the number will layout and i also want the red " perte " to be in negative so if theres more negative it will show in negative also